# Ubuntu-server first start

Tags: server, ifconfig

How do you change network settings?

`ifconfig` gives `ip 192.168.122.1`

(I ping it and the Ethernet card works)

I use  `sudo vi /etc/network/interfeces` then after editing

```
auto eth0 
ifaces eth0 inet dhcp
```

I can not save it. How to save settings?

Comment: 1. `/etc/network/interfeces` => `/etc/network/interfaces` Is that a typo here or a typo in your command? 2. Any notice to why you can not save it?

Comment: In command typing sudo vi /etc/network/interfeces

Comment: in settings changing to

Comment: auto eth0 ifaces eth0 inet dhcp

Comment: and cant save the file

Comment: try nano or mcedit

Answer (score 1):

On the fly

you can configure ip as follows

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.10.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

or static

edit /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.10.0.1
```

then

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: I know how it suppose to look ... I dont know how to save this file .

Comment: open the file using vi here is what you need to do 
vi /etc/network/interfaces 
then press i to enter edit mode, type the settings, then press Esc on your keyboard, later hold on shift key, and press zz (this will save and exit).